# Unable to connect to signalR server from iOS

Tags: ios, signalr, livechat

I am working on chat app where I need to connect to win server which uses signalR framework for real time communication, I am also using the same at my end. When I run the app, it throws an error "Incompatible protocol version". I did debugging the code and found that server code is 1.1 and mine is 1.0, because of this the app is terminating and not connecting to server. I got this updated signalR code for iOS from cococpods. I don't know how to get the 1.1 code.

Could someone tell me how to get this updated code?

Thanks

Comment: And I see there is no 1.1 code in github.

Comment: Hey,Is your issue solved because I am having same issue when connecting to server.

Comment: @Purva: We had other issues as well, so switched to socketio instead of signalR.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply,So is socketIO can be used easily ? I mean are there any issues that can occur using Socket IO

Comment: @Purva : Yes socketio can be used. I had no issues in using it.

Comment: I need to create chat, So is server be created easily in .net ?

Comment: @pura: I am not a .net person. I don't have that info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Does an incompatible protocol version have any impact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072430/does-an-incompatible-protocol-version-have-any-impact).

I'm assuming you're using a third party client for SignalR.  You need to downgrade your server to a compatible protocol version or wait for an updated third party client.  You can use Nuget to pull down specific versions of SignalR.

Comment: Yeah, I am using the 3rd party framework (https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC), even I spoke with server team and they are not willing to downgrade to lower version of the code. I think I should wait for the updated version for iOS.