# Does an incompatible protocol version have any impact?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr.client

I am using a 3rd party library for both my iOS and Android signalr clients. Client has a alpha-2 version of SignalR and server is using the latest 1.0.0 version and hence am facing the error of Incompatible protocol version. If i bypass this protocol match check in my client code then am able to connect without any problem. But would this result in the failures of any features?

Client is not able to receive any data i send from SignalR server, could the incompatible protocol be the reason for it? If so then how can i resolve this Incompatible protocol version problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has a large impact yes!!  When the protocol changes that means that the server will be sending down data that only a client with the correct protocol version will be able to read.

For instance when we started compressing message Id's (used to determine what messages a client has received) we updated the protocol version.  An older client that does not recognize  the updated message Id format will fail to communicate correctly with the server.

I'd recommend downgrading your SignalR server to an alpha-2 build until the third party clients have been successfully updated to 1.0.0 versions.